# After if statment that should change x, x is still the same

Tags: python

I got this short code, mind that I am really new to python, and I dont understand why the x after I run the code is still 45 if my input is 45, or for that matter 55 if my input is 55

```
x = float(input('Enter a number'))
y = 0
if x < 40.0:
    y = (x - 40)
    x = 40.0-y
else:
    y = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have your less than `<` and greater than `>` operators mixed up.

Your if statement says, "if x is less than 40, do the following". Your input tests are 45 or 55, so x is never less than 40, therefore none of the code in your if statement is ever executed.

Comment: Oh, well... Thanks, that was that.

Answer (score 1):

have you checked this condition if x < 40.0:

it might be because the x is less than 40.0

your else statement has no logic to modify the x variable

Comment: Yep...I focued on other things and didnt see the obvious one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your code itself states that if your x is less than 40 change it as x=40-(y)
which in brief is x=40-(x-40). Since input 45(>40) evaluates to False then how is that supposed to run block of code intended for other numbers less than 40

Answer (score 0):

If your `x` variable is set to `45` by the user, then the first `if` statement fails and the program proceeds to your 'else' statement where the x variable is untouched.
By your code, if you wish to change the value of the `x` variable, you need to enter a number below `40.0`.

Answer (score 0):

First condition is not fulfilled if x is greater than or equal to 40.0 ( you are using 45 and 55 ).
but if first condition is fulfilled value of x at the end will not remain same .

if you want to see the value has changed print value of x as follows:

```
if x < 40.0:
    y = (x - 40)
    ***print "Value of x", x, "Val of y", y***
    x = 40.0-y
    ***print "Value of x", x, "Val of y", y***
else:
    y = 0

***print "Value of x", x, "Val of y", y***
```